# Hidden elements in jquery tabs are not visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tabs

I use jquery tabs widget and populate each tab panel with content from another aspx page.
Looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("PENDING", "PendingList", "Admin")%></li>
    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("APPROVED", "ApprovedList", "Admin")%></li>
    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("DENIED/CANCELED", "CanceledList", "Admin")%></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The page that is injected as a content looks like this:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Event name</td><td>Private</td><td>Location</td><td>Start date</td>
    <td>Duration</td><td>Asset</td><td>Contact name</td><td>Email</td><td>Phone</td>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some event Name<input type="hidden" id="bookingId" value="1"></td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>...</td>
      ...
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

On parent page, where the tab widget was placed I try to read values from body of table elemnt.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 function initializeCanceledTab(tabPanel/**/) {
        var tabRows = $(tabPanel).find("table tr");

        tabRows.each(function (index, domEl) {
            var id = $(this).find("input:hidden").val();
            or
            var id = $(this).find("#bookingId:hidden").val();
            or 
            var id = $(this).find("input:has[type='hidden']").val();
        });
 });
```

i can read all values except value in a hidden field. $(this) is a tr element. Inspecting it (innerHTML) showed that there is no hidden input there. But when page rendered firebug and IE development tool show hidden input. 
Did anybody meet this issue? Will be very appreciated if somebody can help. Thank you.

Comment: are you able to see them in viewsource

Comment: @you can do one more thing , just write the jquery code in firebug console and see if you can get the results

Comment: ViewSource shows only what is on the parent page, no tables or other injected elements. I can solve this issue if I write script on content page where is table described. But wanted to have scripts in a one place.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still having problems with this but this should work assuming the content has loaded correctly:

```
var id = $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val();
```

:hidden isn't the same as :text or :button - http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/